# Close popup clicking on overlay - ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a modal popup. How to close the pop-up window by clicking on overlay correctly? ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

```js
export class PopupComponent {
      @ViewChild('window') popup: ElementRef;
      visible = false;
      openPopup: boolean;
      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      overlayClicked(event) {
        if(event.path.indexOf(this.popup.nativeElement) === -1){
          this.visible = false;
        }
}
```

```css
.window__container {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        min-width: 360px;
        z-index: 10000;
}
.overlay {
        position: fixed;
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 2;
        cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<button md-icon-button (click)="openPopup()">Open</button>

<div class="overlay" (click)="overlayClicked($event)">
  <div *ngIf="openPopup" class=window>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Create a slackblitz

Comment: <div #window class="overlay" (click)="overlayClicked($event)"> template variable needs to declare

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the id like this "#window" in the html element and not only setting the class.

```
<div class="overlay" (click)="overlayClicked($event)">
  <div *ngIf="openPopup" #window class=window>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```